# Where can I find the config folder in patch 6.3?

Tags: league-of-legends

I can't find the config folder in my *League Of Legends* folder, I may have deleted it by mistake.

Can this affect my LoL client?
I am on patch 6.3.

Comment: Why do you need the config files? Can't you just repair the game?

Comment: @David Markdown doesn't use HTML tags.  Please read up on how markdown works to learn how to use it for future edits.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of finding the files that are missing and replacing them yourself, why not just run repair mode on your launcher? That will replace any missing files you might think you deleted and the ones you didn't even know you deleted.

Still i will give you an answer on that, go to the directory in which you installed LoL, assuming you installed on the default directory you just go to *C:\Riot Games\League of Legends* and you will most likely have a RADS folder, which is were all the files are, including config if i'm not mistaken.(If you want to do this one, read [@Broken_Code's](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/256651/139515) answer, it is better for this case)

***Honestly***, just do the first option, it's a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

No matter what patch you are on the config folder is always in the root dir of lol always.

> C:\Riot Games\League of Legends

If you mean to say you delete the release folder then you would find that in the rads projects folder(s)

> C:\League of Legends\RADS\projects

Each has information so I do not think that is what you meant. Deleting the root config folder will just force the patcher to download the defaults.